# How to decrease nvidia GPU temperature on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nvidia, gpu, temperature, nvidia-settings

I have ubuntu 18.04 (on dell g5 notebook but it probably does not matter) with installed nvidia 440 driver and I want to decrease GPU performance for decreasing its working temperature. How can I do that?

Comment: Switch to the (probably) built-in Intel video, probably found as a BIOS setting.

Comment: I must admit that I actually NEED nvidia GPU I just want its clock to be lower

Comment: I don't know if the Nvidia utilities can do that. Maybe somebody else knows.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is good if you know how to use it. To reduce overheat:
I am only giving u the steps. for detail, search each step in google.

1. install "psensor" to check temperature. should be <50 deg C for all sensors in idle. Else proceed as below:
2. For nvidia laptops: drivers can cause problem. in terminal search "top". if you find that xorg is running on 100% processor, then disable / uninstall nvidia drivers if any.You may try to change drivers but i just disable them if i dont need them.
3. For power management issue:  check if u are getting low temp when laptop is unplugged but high when plugged in. Then it is power management issue.
   To resolve this, install "tlp". change config file in [/etc/tlp.conf] by gedit text editor: SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=1, AHCL_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=auto, RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=auto.